# Calling LLVM bitcode function in LLVM 2.8

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-gcc

I'm trying to read and call a function parsed from LLVM bitcode in LLVM 2.8. I have everything working apart from the actual call, which crashes the program.

First I have this C code:

```
void hello() {}
```

I've compiled this with:

```
llvm-gcc -c -emit-llvm hello.c -o hello.bc
```

Here's a trimmed down version of the code that's supposed to read it:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;

void callFunction(string file, string function) {
  InitializeNativeTarget();

  LLVMContext context;
  string error;

  MemoryBuffer* buff = MemoryBuffer::getFile(file);
  Module* m = getLazyBitcodeModule(buff, context, &error);

  // Check the module parsed here.
  // ...

  ExecutionEngine* engine = ExecutionEngine::create(m);

  // Check the engine started up correctly here.
  // ...

  Function* func = m->getFunction(function);

  // Check the function was found here.
  // ..

  vector<GenericValue> args(0);

  // This is what crashes.
  engine->runFunction(func, args);
}
```

I've included plenty of LLVM headers, including ExecutionEngine/JIT.h, and the code checks at each step to make sure values aren't NULL. It parses the bitcode, and I have examined the function it finds to confirm it was as expected.

I've also tried building a module and function myself, which works as expected, so the problem definitely arises from the fact that the function is produced by the bitcode.

Comment: It might help to give more information on the exact crash you are seeing (e.g., a backtrace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this running as expected. I was curious if the problem lay in the above process, but this is obviously not the case. The system I was running this as a part of was causing the crash, and the code above does work on its own.